# Metric tensor and lowering of indices

Tags: tensors

In tensor calculus, there is a formula for lowering the index of a vector field to change it to a 1-form:

$g_{kl} v^k = v_l$

where $v^k$ is the component of the original vector field, $v_l$ is the component of the lowered vector field, and $g_{kl}$ is the component of the metric tensor. I know that this formula can be derived by using the following equation:

$v^\flat(w) = g(v, w)$

where $v, w$ are vector fields, $v^\flat$ represents the lowered $v$, and $g$ is the metric tensor. If we now substitute $v = v^k \frac{\partial}{\partial x^k}$, $w = w^l \frac{\partial}{\partial x^l}$, $v^\flat = v_k dx^k$ and $g = g_{ij} dx^i \otimes dx^j$ into the above equation, then after some manipulation, on the LHS we have

$v^\flat(w) = v_lw^l$

and on the RHS we have

$g(v, w) = g_{kl} v^kw^l$

Equating the above two results, we then have

$g_{kl} v^k = v_l$

which is our desired result. However, in tensor calculus, there are other more complicated formlae for lowering the indices of a tensor field, such as the following:

$g_{kl}T^{ki} = T^i_l$

where $T^{ki}$ is the component of a $(2, 0)$-tensor field and $T^i_l$ is the component of the corresponding tensor field with one index lowered. I wonder how the above formula can be derived using a procedure similar to the above.

Comment: You can always write a (2,0) tensor as the tensor product of two vectors.